# NSLayoutConstraint "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" Errors and how to Interpret them

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I am having some issues with constraints which I can't get my head around. I think I would find it really helpful if I understood the error messages (specifically relating to `NSLayoutConstraints`) in the console window better. Here is an example:

I have this constraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: mainView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

Which makes sense to me, I want to make `mainView` the exact same height as `self.view`. However this generates the error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a94fa10 UIView:0x7a9f95c0.height == UIView:0x7a9d1660.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a9488a0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7a9f95c0(110)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a948490 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7a9d1660(430)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a94fa10 UIView:0x7a9f95c0.height == UIView:0x7a9d1660.height>
```

I have commented out all the other constraints except for this one, and yet I still get this error. Am I right in thinking the constraint is conflicting with itself?

Can anyone point me in the right direction with how to fix this problem?

Most importantly, if anyone can help me understand these `NSLayoutConstraint` error messages that would be extremely helpful.

--

Please note I am using Swift here, but I don't mind if the answers are in Objective C.

Comment: Is mainView is Dynamic/Static which is at Interface Builder..?
If it is static then u can select both view and MainView and keep Height Equally constraints to it..!

Comment: I am building all my UIViews programmatically

Comment: set mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO.

Comment: @mistyhua yeah I was being stupid and forgot translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints... again... add this as a proper answer and I will mark you as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO. // ObjC
mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. // Swift

It will work!

thx

Comment: But use false instead of NO.